# ListView items does not fit in Grid cells

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, grid

Help me please. In Xamarin.Forms I have a main ListView containing cards (Frame with Grid). Each Grid has Labels and a ListVew with phones. The ListVew with phones takes up three rows and three columns. I need all the elements of the phone ListView inside the Grid to always be visible (usually their number is up to three, but maybe more) and that the height of the Grid cells will increase if necessary to accommodate all the elements of the phone ViewList. Is this possible to do? Now Grid cells increase in text height in labels but not in PhoneListView height.

```
[MyListView MainView = new MyListView
            {
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
                HasUnevenRows = true,

                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Grid MyGrid = new Grid
                    {
                        RowDefinitions =
                {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0.02, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0.02, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0.02, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) }
                },
                        ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
                }
                    };

...

ListView phonesList = new ListView
                    {
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Never,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                        SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
                        HasUnevenRows = true,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                        {
                            Image phoneButton = new Image { Source = "phone_green.png", HeightRequest = 40, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
                            Label phoneTextLabel = new Label { HeightRequest = 40, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
                            phoneTextLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "phone");
                            return new ViewCell { View = new StackLayout {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                Children = { phoneButton, phoneTextLabel } } };
                        })
                    };
phonesList.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "phones", BindingMode.Default, new PhoneSepConverter());
...
                    DetailGrid.Children.Add(phonesList, 4, 2); 
...
                    Grid.SetColumnSpan(phonesList, 3);
                    Grid.SetRowSpan(phonesList, 3);
...
Frame ListItem = new Frame { Content = MyGrid };
                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = ListItem
                    };
})
            };][1]
```

Comment: Here is the link to the screenshot https://ibb.co/TRhGZtP

Comment: Do you mean to make all ListItem visible at initial? No need fro scrolling?

Comment: Yes. No need for scrolling.

Comment: Then why don't you use StackLayout with [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) instead of ListView?

Comment: Did not know about BindableLayout, I will try, thanks

Comment: I'll give you a sample from kind of implementing your requirement in the answers...

Comment: Just now checked. You will also need to change the `mainListView` from `ListView` to `CollectionView` to set the `SizingStrategy` to Measure All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple StackLayout with BindableLayout as you Don't want a scrollable view.

Since the `ItemSizingStrategy` is not available in ListView, all the Items are render as the same size of first item. Which would not suit your cause.

Use `CollectionView` instead of `ListView` for `mainListView` and set the `ItemSizingStrategy` to `MeasureAllItems`.

```cs
CollectionView mainListView = new CollectionView();
mainListView.ItemsSource = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item(){Name = "First", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1",} },
    new Item(){Name = "Second", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Third", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Fourth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Fifth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Sixth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Seventh", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Eight", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Ninth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Tenth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Eleventh", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Tweleth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Thirteenth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3", "Phone 4"} },
    new Item(){Name = "Fourteenth", Phones = new List<string>(){ "Pnone 1", "Phone 2"} },
};

mainListView.ItemSizingStrategy = ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureAllItems;

mainListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    Frame frame = new Frame()
    {
        CornerRadius = 0,
        BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
    };

    Grid mainItemGrid = new Grid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions =
        {
            new ColumnDefinition(){Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)}
        }
    };

    StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout()
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };
    stackLayout.SetBinding(BindableLayout.ItemsSourceProperty, "Phones");
    BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate(stackLayout, new DataTemplate(() => {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
        return label;
    }));

    mainItemGrid.Children.Add(
        new Label() { Text = "Some text" }
        , 0, 0);

    mainItemGrid.Children.Add(
        stackLayout, 1, 0);

    frame.Padding = 1;
    frame.Content = mainItemGrid;

    mainItemGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
    return frame;
});
```

UI result

[image]

Please check if this helps you...

Comment: Thanks! Replacing mainListView did not solve my problem, but I replaced ListView phonesList with stackLayout phonesList + BindableLayout, and set RowDefinition Height from Star to Auto and that solved my question! Thanks again!